# How do I create a variable inside a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

This may be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find any good resources on this.

I currently have the following lambda:

```
public static final Predicate<Path> TEXT = path -> (path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt") || (path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".text")));
```

I want apply the path.toString().toLowerCase result to a variable so that I can simply call:

```
(result.endsWith(".txt") || result.endsWith(".text"))
```

How can I do this in a lambda expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a block instead of an expression for the lambda expression body:

```
public static final Predicate<Path> TEXT = path -> {
    String result = path.toString().toLowerCase();
    return result.endsWith(".txt") || result.endsWith(".text");
};
```